# Can't request logs in elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to request logs of my elastic beanstalk environment and I'm using the UI for it. However, upon requesting the logs, there's a loading period after which the logs don't show up. How can I fix this?[image]

Comment: You can ssh to the instance and inspect the logs from there.

Comment: How do I ssh to inspect the logs? I'm currently running into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66833531/unable-to-see-logs-in-elastic-beanstalk-cli

Comment: Usually `eb ssh` should be enough.

Comment: I am having the same issue... EB won't generate logs... That is a waste of time