# Unable to see logs in elastic beanstalk cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to see logs of my elastic beanstalk environment in the command line, for which I'm doing the following:

```
eb logs --cloudwatch-logs enable --cloudwatch-log-source instance Humboialpha2021-env
```

However, I'm seeing the following error:

```
Enabling instance log streaming to CloudWatch for your environment
After the environment is updated you can view your logs by following the link:
https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=us-east-1#logs:prefix=/aws/elasticbeanstalk/Humboialpha2021-env/
Printing Status:
2021-03-27 16:19:05    INFO    Environment update is starting.      
2021-03-27 16:19:16    INFO    Updating environment Humboialpha2021-env's configuration settings.
2021-03-27 16:19:54    INFO    Instance deployment successfully detected a JAR file in your source bundle.
2021-03-27 16:19:57    INFO    Instance deployment successfully generated a 'Procfile'.
2021-03-27 16:19:58    ERROR   Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.
2021-03-27 16:20:02    ERROR   [Instance: i-04fb7a3d67a219ca7] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Engine execution has encountered an error..
2021-03-27 16:20:02    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
2021-03-27 16:20:02    ERROR   Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-04fb7a3d67a219ca7'. Aborting the operation.
2021-03-27 16:20:03    ERROR   Failed to deploy configuration.      
                                                                      
ERROR: ServiceError - Failed to deploy configuration.
```

How to fix this?